# Cannot create `rCharts` demo using `nvd3`

Tags: r, rcharts

I want to use the `rCharts` library to generate some plots, so I am giving the examples on their [website](http://ramnathv.github.io/posts/rcharts-nvd3/) a try.

Seems like I cannot get the demo to work, I paste the following code in a markdown file (I first tried pasting it into the console in `RStudio`).

```
library(rCharts)
options(
  rcharts.mode = 'iframesrc', 
  rcharts.cdn = TRUE,
  RCHART_WIDTH = 600,
  RCHART_HEIGHT = 400
)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(tidy = F, results = 'asis', comment = NA)

dat <- data.frame(
  t = rep(0:23, each = 4), 
  var = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4), 
  val = round(runif(4*24,0,50))
)
p8 <- nPlot(val ~ t, group =  'var', data = dat, 
 type = 'stackedAreaChart', id = 'chart'
)
p8
```

I get the following output (pasted at the end of the post), but no plot (I also clicked on `Open in Browser` in the `RStudio` browser window, but still don't see any plot.

My info on `R` session is as follows:

```
Session info --------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.98.1103)         
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2015-10-07
```

and my `rCharts` version is `0.4.5`.

I am completely new to `rCharts` and using any kind of `javascript` library for charting, so any help will be much appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Output from the code above (I am only pasting the top portion, as it is quite long ..)

```
## <iframe srcdoc=' &lt;!doctype HTML&gt;
## &lt;meta charset = &#039;utf-8&#039;&gt;
## &lt;html&gt;
##   &lt;head&gt;
##     &lt;link rel=&#039;stylesheet&#039; href=&#039;//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nv.d3.min.css&#039;&gt;
##     
##     &lt;script src=&#039;//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js&#039; type=&#039;text/javascript&#039;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
##     &lt;script src=&#039;//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js&#039; type=&#039;text/javascript&#039;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
##     &lt;script src=&#039;//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nv.d3.min.js&#039; type=&#039;text/javascript&#039;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
##     &lt;script src=&#039;//nvd3.org/assets/lib/fisheye.js&#039; type=&#039;text/javascript&#039;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
##     
##     &lt;style&gt;
##     .rChart {
##       display: block;
##       margin-left: auto; 
##       margin-right: auto;
##       width: 600px;
##       height: 400px;
##     }  
##     &lt;/style&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run the following in R Studio (on a mac) as an R markdown file I *almost* get what you want.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "7 Oct 2015"
output: html_document
---
```{r}

library(rCharts)
options(
  rcharts.mode = 'iframesrc', 
  rcharts.cdn = TRUE,
  RCHART_WIDTH = 600,
  RCHART_HEIGHT = 400
)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(tidy = F, results = 'asis', comment = NA)

dat <- data.frame(
  t = rep(0:23, each = 4), 
  var = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4), 
  val = round(runif(4*24,0,50))
)
p8 <- nPlot(val ~ t, group =  'var', data = dat, 
            type = 'stackedAreaChart', id = 'chart'
)
```

```{r fig=TRUE, results='asis'}
p8
```
````

One problem is that the browser in R Studio actually doesn't always work for rendering rCharts. I seem to recall that there was a fix for this but I simply cannot remember what it was (or find it). However, when you knit the file above you get an `html` file and if you open that up in you favorite browser then the graph shows. I think it has something to do with the javascript/css links but my memory is hazy.

Comment: Thank you @ekstroem, I tried pasting the code you have. I don't get the output I was getting before (pasted at the end of my post), now I don't get anything in my `html` except my code. I tried using `Open in Browser`, but chrome wheel keeps spinning .. I am sure there is something wrong my CSS/JS setting ..

Comment: Are you running the `dev` version of rCharts? Mine is listed as 0.4.2. Try `install_github('ramnathv/rCharts@dev')`

Comment: I am using version `0.4.5`, I am having problems in installing the `dev` version though.

Comment: I have R version `3.1.2` (which I cannot update, due to permissions on my laptop) and `base64enc` is not available for my `3.1.2`. `base64enc` is required for the `dev` version in `rCharts`. I can install `rCharts` using `github_install(ramnathv/rCharts)` though.